# What software is included in the Monero Core?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monerod

What software is included in the Monero Core?

https://getmonero.org/downloads/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several programs the most important being `simplewallet` and `bitmonerod`

There is also a `simpleminer` a `blockchain_import` and `blockchain_converter` tool.

For each account that you create with `simplewallet` an address, wallet and keys file will be created